# Doctrine 3 does not create the foreign key - PDOException: "Column 'tour_id' cannot be null"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to insert a new record in the database.

I have two tables `bootstrap_tour` and `bootstrap_tour_step`.

`id` of `boostrap_tour` table is the foreign key `tour_id` in the `bootstrap_tour_step` table.

The corresponding entities look as follows:

**BootstrapTour.php**

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 * @JMS\Groups({"auth_read_postbootstraptours"})
 * @JMS\Type("integer")
 * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getId")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection[BootstrapTourStep]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BootstrapTourStep", mappedBy="bootstrapTour", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 * @JMS\Groups({"auth_read_postbootstraptours"})
 */
private $bootstrapTourSteps;

/**
 * Object instantiation.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->bootstrapTourSteps = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Sets a collection of BootstrapTourStep objects.
 *
 * @param ArrayCollection|null $bootstrapTourSteps
 *
 * @return BootstrapTour
 */
public function setBootstrapTourSteps(?ArrayCollection $bootstrapTourSteps): BootstrapTour
{
    $this->bootstrapTourSteps = $bootstrapTourSteps;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Returns a collection of BootstrapTourStep objects.
 *
 * @return Collection[BootstrapTourStep]|null
 */
public function getBootstrapTourSteps(): ?Collection
{
    return $this->bootstrapTourSteps;
}

/**
 * Adds a Step to the tour.
 *
 * @return BootstrapTour
 */
public function addBootstrapTourStep(BootstrapTourStep $bootstrapTourStep): BootstrapTour
{
    $bootstrapTourStep->setBootstrapTour($this);
    $this->bootstrapTourSteps[] = $bootstrapTourStep;

    return $this;
}
```

**BootstrapTourStep.php**

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @JMS\Groups({"auth_read_getbootstraptours"})
 * @JMS\Type("integer")
 * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getId")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BootstrapTour", inversedBy="bootstrapTourSteps")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tour_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * 
 * @JMS\Groups({"auth_read_postbootstraptours"})
 * @JMS\Type("EN\CentralAdmin\DoctrineBundle\Entity\BootstrapTour")
 * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getBootstrapTour", setter="setBootstrapTour")
 */
private $bootstrapTour;

/**
 * Gets the BootstrapTour 
 * 
 * @return BootstrapTour|null
 */
public function getBootstrapTour(): ?BootstrapTour
{
    return $this->bootstrapTour;
}

/**
 * Sets a BootstrapTour
 * 
 * @param BootstrapTour $bootstrapTour
 * @return BootstrapTourStep
 */
public function setBootstrapTour(BootstrapTour $bootstrapTour): BootstrapTourStep
{
    $this->bootstrapTour = $bootstrapTour;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * A list of reference proxies.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getReferenceProxies(): array
{
    return [ 
        'BootstrapTour'
    ];
}
```

My controller Action :

```
$bootstrapTourService = $this->getCentralAdminEntityService('BootstrapTour');
$bootstrapTourService->persist($tourType, true);
```

I am able to select the data using this but in case of adding new record I am getting the following exception:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tour_id' cannot be null

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the relation to the tour on the steps when adding a collection of steps. This way the step entities are added to the tour **but** the steps themselves don't know which tour they belong to.

If now doctrine tries to persist the steps their reference to the tour is missing and therefore you get the missing `tour_id` exception.

This ...

```
public function setBootstrapTourSteps(?ArrayCollection $bootstrapTourSteps): BootstrapTour
{
    $this->bootstrapTourSteps = $bootstrapTourSteps;

    return $this;
}
```

... should be:

```
public function setBootstrapTourSteps(?ArrayCollection $bootstrapTourSteps): BootstrapTour
{
    $this->bootstrapTourSteps = new ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($bootstrapTourSteps as $step) {
      $step->setBootstrapTour($this);
      $this->bootstrapTourSteps->add($step);
    }

    return $this;
}
```